# How to create a single instance of the class Object which contains data not limited to one instance?

Tags: java, class, oop

Please consider the following situation, which is belongs to a "Fire and Security Alarm Monitoring System" of a building.

I have 3 classes, `Zone`, `Controller` and `Camera`. `Controller` is similar to the central control unit of a building. `Controller` controls `Camera`s so there is an array of `Camera` objects in `Controller`. Controller is capable of doing various tasks such as read data from cameras, turn off cameras, turn on, record data to the database etc.

**Controller.java**

```
    public class Controller
    {
            private Camera[] camera;

             public byte[] getVideo()
            {
            }
    }
```

The Zone class reads data from the controller, and pass commands to the controller.

**Zone.java**

```
 public Zone extends JPanel
    {
             private Controller ctrl;
    }
```

There are 6 Zone objects, because these zones are similar to "Rooms" in the building. Different zones will have different number of cameras, and will pass different commands to the `Controller`

Even though there are 6 zone objects there should be a one Controller, because it is the central control unit, and there cannot be different different Control units for different different zones. But "Controller" should have differnet different camera objects which are belongs to different zones. For an example, 5 cameras for zone1, 2 cameras for zone 2 etc. So controller can control camera objects in different ways.

Controller does things which affects to the whole building as well. For an example, Raising the security alarm.

However if I create new Controller objects for each and every zone, then I will not be able to perform the tasks which are affected to the whole building. If I make controller singliten pattern then I will not be able to create different camera objects for different zones and get their data seperatly using the getter methods.

So, how can I achieve the both? Again, I think there should be one controller because a building cannot have number of controller for number of rooms.

Comment: Why don't you associate cameras with your zones, instead of with the controller?

Comment: "_If I make controller singleton pattern then I will not be able to create different camera objects for different zones and get their data seperatly using the getter methods_" **Yes, you can,** if you do what Perception says in the comment above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want one `Controller`, and a bunch of `Zone`s with `Camera`s.

```
public class Controller {

    private ArrayList<Zone> zones;

}
```

... and ...

```
public class Zone {

    private ArrayList<Camera> cameras;

    public byte[] getVideo() {
        //...
    }
}
```

This way, the `Controller` has reference to all `Zone`s (and, indirectly, all `Camera`s, assuming you have the appropriate getters and setters).  Also, as a side note, depending on your design it probably makes more sense to have `getVideo()` be a part of the `Camera` class, unless the "video" is a collection of all `Camera`s' feeds.

Comment: Great! Thanks a lot! Sorry for the delay of my reply, it took a while to change a complete class :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding, I would go for:

- 1 Singleton Controller which has static fatory methods to create Zone object
- This Controller will also have multiple Zone objects in it as instance variables: HAS-A relationship
- Zone Objects which can create Camera objects and hold them as instance variables : HAS-A relationship

This way seems more logical

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right, you have two options:

**Option 1:**
`Zone` contains a list of cameras.

**Option 2:**
`Controller` contains a map from `Zone` to `Camera`:

```
public class Controller {
  Map<Zone, Camera> zoneCameras;
  ...
}
```

Comment: Option 2 won't allow more than one camera per zone.

Comment: Ah, yeah, but you can use a `Map<Zone, List<Camera>>`.

Comment: In that case I'd prefer a `MultiMap`

Comment: Yeah, but for that you need Guava... ;-)

Comment: I know. I always try to use the right tool for my requirements ;)